# Extracting direction of dominant sinusoids from an image in terms of angles

Tags: autocorrelation

Here is a sample image. 
[image]

What I am looking to do is compute the dominant "wrinkle" directions.
The dominant wrinkle directions can be seen in the following FFT, roughly, by drawing a line through the highest valued set of points in the spectrum.
[image: fft]

I have been told that a potential way to find this direction would be to look at the auto-correlation `scipy.signal.correlate2d`.
I have not worked with this tool before, so I want to make sure my idea is correct. 
The way that I think this will work is by using the FFT data to find the largest components of the signal. 
Say for example, I look at the largest two components. 
I can construct two images, one for each of the largest components, lets call the images `dominant1` and `dominant2`.

For each image, I could then look at:

```
scipy.signal.correlate2d(image,dominant1) 
scipy.signal.correlate2d(image,dominant2)
```

I believe that this will return a matrix that shows where the features are in the `image` that most agree with the signals `dominant1` and `dominant2`.

If this interpretation is correct, I am still unsure of how to extract the `dominant_angle1` and `dominant_angle2` say. Suppose that the horizontal direction in the image as shown above is `x` and the vertical is `y`. I would like `dominant_angle1/2` to be the angle off of the x-axis.

Any comments, suggestions for better approaches, will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the image of? I'm currently finishing off a paper that deals with modelling these kinds of image structures.

Comment: It is an image of a gold nano layer on a substrate that was stressed in such a way to form "wrinkles".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work

1. Perform FFT

$$F(u,v) = \mathcal{F}[f](x,y)$$

2. Multiply magnitude by 2nd order circular harmonic and sum

$$c = \sum_u \sum_v |F(u,v)|  e^{i 2 \phi}$$

where $\phi = \arg (u + iv)$

3. Angle is half of argument

$$\theta = \arg(c) / 2 $$

Here is some matlab code:

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('eNb2pye.jpg'));
F = fft2(I);
[~,~,r,th] = FFTMesh(size(I));
c = sum(sum(abs(F) .* exp(1i.*2.*th)));
direction = angle(c)/2
```

which uses the following function to general the spectrum u,v and radial coordinates

```
function [ux,uy,r,th] = FFTMesh(sizeM)
rows = sizeM(1);
cols = sizeM(2);
[ux, uy] = meshgrid(([1:cols]-(fix(cols/2)+1))/(cols-mod(cols,2)), ...
    ([1:rows]-(fix(rows/2)+1))/(rows-mod(rows,2)));
ux = ifftshift(ux);   % Quadrant shift to put 0 frequency at the corners
uy = ifftshift(uy);
% Convert to polar coordinates
th = atan2(uy,ux);
r = sqrt(ux.^2 + uy.^2);
end
```

Comment: The angle $\theta$ is the dominant angle of wrinkling? Meaning that in the bottom left of the FFT spectrum I posted, $\theta$ would be the angle off of the horizontal axis to the line that passes through a majority of the dominant values in the spectrum?

Comment: $\theta$ would be the average angle of the frequency spectrum. Since the spectrum is in conjugate pairs it is a double angle.

Comment: This is very useful. How did you learn about this? I'm curious just to take a look at some references.

Comment: I'm working on sinusoidal signal models for my PhD that will be hopefully finished soon. I'm not sure there are references for the above. To get some intuition, take the absolute value of the FFT, then convert it to polar coordinates. Try this code:  `F = fftshift(abs(fft2(I)));  [row,col,r,th] = FFTMesh(size(F)); [ri,thi] = meshgrid(linspace(0,0.5,200),linspace(0,2*pi,400)); Fpolar = interp2(fftshift(row),fftshift(col),F,ri.*cos(thi),ri.*sin(thi)); imagesc(log(F)); title('FT'); pause; imagesc(log(Fpolar)); title('FT polar coords'); pause;`

Comment: If you sum the rows of `Fpolar` you will get a 1-D signal that is the average of the spectrum along each radial line. It will have two main peaks where the orientation is concentrated. The $e^(i 2 \theta)$ sum part of the above is equivalent to calculating the 2nd order Fourier series coefficient of the this 1-D signal of sums along each radial direction.

Comment: The 1-D signal probably gives you a bit more info than just the main orientation. Note there will be some lines corresponding to the edges of the image, and thus you may want to window the image to lessen this effect.

Comment: BTW is this for uni PhD / research? I have some even better techniques you could use, but not properly published yet if you wish to collaborate.

Comment: Yes, this is sort of for uni research. I recently graduated from a Masters program and this was a project I was working on. Now I am casually working on the project, to pick up skills in image analysis. If I find something interesting I will pass it along to the group I worked with. Let's chat about collab https://gitter.im/callmeskywalker/dsp-chat